# unable to install from binary .bz2 2.79 or 2.8 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: import

I downloaded the bz2 files, i ran tar -xjf on the file i cd'd to the directory and ran ./configure and bash returns no such file or directory The reason I'm doing this is because the apt repository version which installs has no mp4 import option

Comment: You don't need to compile the program. Simply download the file from https://www.blender.org/download/  extract the bz2 files, open the created folder and run the executable file called blender